# Not allowed to load local resource (Webkit)

Tags: css, haskell, svg, webkit

I'm writing app based on webkit (haskell).
I ran into unpleasant stuff: When I try to load image via 'file:', I get this console message: `Not allowed to load local resource: file://resources/something.svg`.

To fix it I wrote a few lines of code:

```
wvSettings <- webViewGetWebSettings webView
set wvSettings [webSettingsEnableUniversalAccessFromFileUris := True]
webViewSetWebSettings webView wvSettings
```

But the problem remained. So what should I do?

Comment: I'm usually too lazy to figure these things out. It's way faster to just fire up a local web server. I usually run `python3 -m http.server 8000` from the directory I want to have available. Not sure if this applies to your case and it doesn't really solve the core issue, so just pointing it out as a possible option.